# How to remesh into tris with equally spaced vertices?

Tags: mesh, remesh

I'm looking for a way to basically convert my mesh to tris with equally spaced vertices.

Here I made a quick example below with a sphere and a cube:
[image]

The number of tris at the end doesn't really matter, but I need the vertices to be equally spaced.

Comment: Have you considered using the Remesh modifier, applying it, and then “Triangulate faces“?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Yes. But it only works for simple meshes. Tried it with Suzanne, the vertices were not evenly spaced.

Comment: I'm also curious about this. Grasshopper in Rhino has this feature (which is a CAD package from McNeel).